# How to list only the project dependencies jars in Gradle task

Tags: gradle, jar

In my case I have multiproject build with many subprojects and sub/subprojects.

Then I would like to be able to call this task from different subprojects to produce different jars set (basing on the project dependencies). In that way I would be able to create separate distribution for different subprojects.

I've come to the stage that I can list all of projects deps jars in an ugly way:

```
task showJars {
    doLast {
        if( configurations && configurations.getByName('compile') ) {
            configurations.compile.collect {
                if( !it.toString().contains('.gradle') )
                    println(it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am working on a task to gather all project jars in one directory to create distribution for the app. Is there any clean way to achieve this ?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please clarify the question? What's the desired output?

Comment: I have multiproject build. Every subproject in this build outputs a jar as a result of `gradle jar` task. There are also dependencies between subprojects. I want to define a task which will create a projects jars and then copy them to one directory. 

The first part is to simply invoke `gradle jar` in the root or one of the subprojects, the second is to collect the project jars and copy  them to one location.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to tweak the snippet below depending on your project and configuration, but this should give you the general idea:

```
task copyProjectDependencies << {
    file("build/project-dependencies").deleteDir()
    subprojects.findAll().each { project ->
        copy {
            from project.jar
            from project.configurations.runtime
            into "build/project-dependencies/jars"
        }
    }
}
```

You can also look at gradle's bundled [application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html):

```
apply plugin: 'application'
```

From the docs:

> The Application plugin facilitates creating an executable JVM application. It makes it easy to start the application locally during development, and to packaging the application as a TAR and/or ZIP including operating system specific start scripts.

It will package it up as an archive with all dependencies.

Comment: Thank for this try. Unfortunately this is not exactly my case. I would like to get the jars from the dependent projects of the project that invoke the task. I will update my question. Thank you :)